How to connect Tridion Sites 10 Core service using PowerShell and Access Management
Recently we upgraded to Tridion Sites 10.0 and Access Management is enabled for Coreservice.
How we can use PowerShell Modules of Tridion Coreservice?

In Tridion Sites 10.0 with Access Management enabled, you can still continue using PowerShell modules to access the Coreservice by enabling basic authentication.
Firstly, ensure basic authentication is enabled for the web services in IIS by executing the following PowerShell cmdlet on the Content Manager (CM) server:

Set-WebConfigurationProperty -filter
"/system.webServer/security/authentication/basicAuthentication" -name
enabled -value true -PSPath "IIS:" -location "Tridion Sites Content
Manager/webservices"

Next, install the Tridion-CoreService module and configure it to use basic authentication:

 Install-Module -Name Tridion-CoreService
 $ServiceAccountPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString "password" -AsPlainText -Force
 $ServiceAccountCredential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("username", $ServiceAccountPassword)
    
 Set-TridionCoreServiceSettings -Version "Sites-9.0" -HostName "yourtridion.sitescms.com" -ConnectionType 'Basic' -CredentialType 'Windows' -Credential $ServiceAccountCredential #For Http
 Set-TridionCoreServiceSettings -Version "Sites-9.0" -HostName "yourtridion.sitescms.com" -ConnectionType "Basic-SSL" -CredentialType "Basic" -Credential "username" -Persist #For Https    

 $core = Get-TridionCoreServiceClient
 Write-Host "CoreService Api Version:" $core.GetApiVersion() -ForegroundColor Yellow # The simplest test 

This setup allows seamless integration with Tridion Coreservice using PowerShell modules and also working fine with DXA CM Import and Upgrade scripts.
Atleast I tested and used with sites 10 setup, it works for me
I hope it helps
